# JavaScript: Adding static methods to objects in two different ways

Tags: javascript, methods

What is the difference between below approaches for adding methods to an object:

```
// Appending methods to a function using nested functions
var myObj1 = {

    myMethod : function() {
        console.log('myObj1.myMethod was called');
    },

    myOtherMethod : function() {
    },

    myOtherOtherMethod : function() {
    }
}

// Appending methods to a function using the dot operator:
var myObj2 = {};

myObj2.myMethod = function(){
    console.log('myObj2.myMethod was called');
}

myObj2.myOtherMethod = function(){
}

myObj2.myOtherOtherMethod = function(){
}    

myObj1.myMethod(); // myObj1.myMethod was called
myObj2.myMethod(); // myObj2.myMethod was called
```

Both do the same thing. Besides the different syntax, is one approach preferred over the other? From my point of view, both approaches simply add methods (or function if you like) to an object.

http://jsfiddle.net/NK35z/

​

Comment: You could also do `myObj2["myOtherOtherOtherMethod"] = function() {};`

Answer (score 2):

The two are semantically identical. The object literal syntax is preferred since it is more clear what you are doing and it also gives the JavaScript engine a chance to optimize the result.

Comment: Great! Thanks for all your comments. This definitely cleared up a few things for me.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same. You'll have to use the dot/square brackets accessor when you don't want to overwrite properties/methods that already exist on the object.

Comment: How does using the dot accessor method prevent overwriting current values of named properties?

Comment: @RobG when it's used instead of assigning a new object. Bad choice of words?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between both those ways of declaring objects/functions.  If you mean static methods as in 'they don't change', that will work great.

They are not static methods in the traditional sense.  Every time you create an object like that, it will have its own unique representation of it in memory.  This means instead of one function in memory, you will have one function for each instance of that object (n copies of the function).

In order to make static methods (in the classical OOP sense, methods shared by a class (in JavaScript there are no classes, so objects using the same constructor/prototype) that do not require an instance), you can't really do it.  But if you want the functions to only occupy one space in memory, you must use the [Constructor Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript):

```
function Foo()
{
    //we won't assign any properties here.
}

Foo.prototype.method1 = function(var1, var2){
    //don't use `this` here if you want the method to be truly static.
    //static methods shouldn't try and access instance members.
};

Foo.prototype.method2 = function(var2, var3){
   //whatever goes here
};

// Methods on the prototype are shared by all objects of foo, so we can create a new Foo
var f = new Foo();
foo.method1(1,2); // also works.
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have classes.  It uses prototypical inheritance. There's really nothing that mimics a static method. +1 though for the constructor pattern.

Comment: @helixed That is true, and I will edit accordingly.  The point is that extra memory is not used.

Comment: What I mean is that there are no static methods at all.  Prototypical inheritance means that objects inherit from other objects.  All objects are already "instances" in JS.  I know it's a quibble, but you're not really creating static methods.  You're creating regular methods that use prototypical inheritance.

Comment: Are they not static in the nature that they occupy only one space in memory?

Comment: No.  According to Wikipedia: "Static methods neither require an instance of the class nor can they implicitly access the data (or this, self, Me, etc.) of such an instance." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods

Comment: However, the constructor function can have methods.  You could do `Foo.bar = function() {};`.  This isn't the same thing as a static function though.  It's adding a method to a different object (the constructor function).  And you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's no practical difference. Adding properties in a object literal makes sense where you know everything up front and can just assigne values. Adding properties one at a time make sense where you need to to some work before adding the method, e.g.:

```
var obj = {
  /* define some stuff here */
};

if ( whatever ) {
  obj.fn = function(){/* logic A */}
} else {
  obj.fn = function(){/* logic B */}
}
```

There is no right or wrong way, use whatever suits best in each case. It's ok to use both for the same object.